# How do I install `mmm-mode` (through MELPA)?

Tags: package-repositories, mmm-mode

mmm-mode [is](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/?q=mmm-mode) available on Melpa.

Yet both

```
`M-x` `list-packages` `C-s` `mmm-mode`
```

and

```
`M-x` `package-install` `mmm-mode`
```

suggest that it's not.

How do I install mmm-mode (through MELPA)?

Comment: `mmm-mode` is not in melpa anymore, it's actually in ELPA now.

Comment: voted to close as unclear, as the question is outdated (`mmm-mode` isn't in `melpa` anymore), and the description provided in comments suggests the actual problem is unrelated to `mmm-mode` and `melpa`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the melpa repository to your package archives.

In your `.emacs` init file you have to add the following lines:

[image]

Then, when listing the available packages, you will find `mmm-mode`:

[image]

Comment: I had just one (https://stable.melpa.org/packages/). Adding the two you suggest does not help. I'm using Emacs 25 (and so the third you suggest does not apply).

Comment: Hmm, that seems strange. Those are the only repositories I have. If you see in the second image, my mmm-mode comes from MELPA, so adding the source https://melpa.org/packages should allow you to get it. Make sure to add the package and then run `M-x package-list-packages`. Which emacs version are you using?

Comment: If I type `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_9` in the Terminal, with a `.emacs` containing (require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("MELPA Stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("MELPA" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-initialize)
, and then  call `package-list-packages`, Emacs crashes. I'm running GNU Emacs 25.3.1 on High Sierra. I guess it's more serious than just a lack of mmm-mode.

Comment: It's not specific to 25.3.1. Emacs 25.2.1 also crashes in that exact setup. Not sure if it happens on Sierra or El Capitan.

Comment: The `.emacs` init file should be in your home directory, for instance, in my case it is in `/Users/martin/`. That is the file that gets loaded when emacs starts. The other one I think it is a system example file. You can verify which  init file gets loaded with `C-h v user-init-file [RET]`

Comment: I was indeed talking about ~/.emacs

Comment: Maybe it is that you are trying to set up two different MELPA package sources. Have you tried leaving only melpa.org/packages/ ? Maybe the two have some kind of conflict. Try adding only melpa.org/packages, comment out the rest of the sources, and see what happens. That is what I would do, anyway.